# Docker - Pull library from a private gitlab repo

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm trying to create a Docker image of python and to add a python library created by my company and hosted on gitlab (not public).

My Docker file is :

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install https://gitlab.criteois.com/ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip

WORKDIR home

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

It looks like the step 5/7 is failing :

```
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install https://gitlab.criteois.com/ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip
 ---> Running in 8f04623ef493
Collecting https://gitlab.criteois.com/ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8f926ae0f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname',)': /ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install https://gitlab.criteois.com/ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm suspecting some permission issue due to networking between docker on the host because when I run

```
cbslax@cbslax-desktop:~/Documents/DockerCriteoPy$ curl https://gitlab.criteois.com/ax-analytics/CriteoPy/repository/pep_8/archive.zip --output CriteoPy-Pep-8.zip
```

I'm able to download the library without any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the **--network host** argument to your build command. It's not recommended but you will be able to see if there's an issue with the default bridge network that Docker creates by default.

Example

```
$ docker build <other args> --network host .
```

With the --network host argument, basically you are telling Docker to use your local network instead of the default bridge it created.

Comment: is there a way to setup the bridge within the Dockerfile ?

Comment: actually, if you don't specify a --network value, the bridge network is created by default. Here is an awesome explanation about Docker networking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1